# How to speed up runtime Java code instrumentation?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I made a Java agent which is attached to a JVM during **runtime** and instruments all the loaded project classes and inserts some logging statements. There are 11k classes in total. I measured the total time taken by the `transform` method of my `ClassFileTransformer` and it was 3 seconds. But the duration of the whole instrumentation process takes about 30 seconds.
This is how I retransform my classes:

```
 instrumentation.retransformClasses(myClassesArray);
```

I assume most time is taken up by the JVM to reload changed classes. Is that right? How can I speed up the instrumentation process?

**Update**:
When my agent is attached,

```java
instrumentation.addTransformer(new MyTransfomer(), true);
instrumentation.retransformClasses(retransformClassArray);
```

is called only **once**.

Then `MyTransfomer` class instruments the classes and measures the total duration time of instrumentation:

```java
public class MyTransfomer implements ClassFileTransformer {
private long total = 0;
private long min = ..., max = ...;

public final byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classFileBuffer) {
   long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
   if(s < min) min = s;
   if(s > max) max = s;
   byte[] transformed = this.transformInner(loader, className, classFileBuffer);

   this.total += System.currentTimeMillis() - s;
   
   return transformed;
  }
}
```

After all the classes are instrumented(from the initial array) (a global cache keeps track of the instrumented classes) `total` is printed and it will be ~3 seconds. But `max-min` is ~30 seconds.

**Update 2:**

After looking at the stack trace this is what happens:
I call

```
instrumentation.retransformClasses(retransformClassArray);
```

which calls the native method `retransformClasses0()`. After some time(!) the JVM calls the `transform()` method of the `sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl` class(but this method takes only one class at a time, so the JVM calls this method multiple times consecutively), which calls `transform()` on the `sun.instrument.TransformerManager` object which has a list with the all the `ClassTransformers` registered and calls each of these transformers to transform the class(**I have only one transformer registered!!**).

So to my opinion, most of the time is spent in the JVM (after `retransformClasses0()` is called and before each call to `sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform()`). Is there a way to reduce the time needed by the JVM to carry out this task?

Comment: It is almost impossible to help without the source code, the version of java, and the classpath.  Can you add it to the question or create a github project?

Comment: @Jeff updated with the code.

Comment: Really need to see, if possible, what transformInner is doing.  Also I would suggest logging each class execution time to see if specific classes are at issue.

Comment: Are there other class file transformers registered in the JVM?

Comment: @Holger, no there aren't

Comment: the code of the actual transformation is missing, so it cannot be analysed for a bottleneck.

Comment: @Holger, please see my second update, I have only one transformer registered indeed. If I had more transformers, it would have made sense that I get a larger execution time because they are executed serially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correction:**

<del>Because the `retransformClasses(classArr)`
will not retransform all the elements in the `classArr` at once, instead it will retransform each of them as needed(eg. while linking).(refer to the jdk [`VM_RedefineClasses`][1] and [`jvmtiEnv`][2])</del>, it does **retransform** all of them at once.

**What retransformClasses() does:**

1. Transfer control to native layer, and give it a class list which we want to transform
2. For every class to be transformed, the native code tries to get a new version by calling our java transformer, this leads to a transfer of control between the java code and native.
3. The native code replace the appropriate parts of internal representation by the given new class version one another.

**In step 1:**

`java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#retransformClasses` calls `sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl#retransformClasses0` which is a JNI method, the control will be transferred to native layer.

```c
// src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiEnv.cpp
jvmtiError
JvmtiEnv::RetransformClasses(jint class_count, const jclass* classes) {
  ...
  VM_RedefineClasses op(class_count, class_definitions, jvmti_class_load_kind_retransform);
  VMThread::execute(&op);
  ...
} /* end RetransformClasses */
```

**In step 2:**

This step is implemented by `KlassFactory::create_from_stream`, this procedure will post a `ClassFileLoadHook` event whose callback can acquire the transformed bytecode by invoking the java transformer method. In this step, the control will switch back and forth between native code and java code.

```c
// src/hotspot/share/classfile/klassFactory.cpp
// check and post a ClassFileLoadHook event before loading a class
// Skip this processing for VM hidden or anonymous classes
if (!cl_info.is_hidden() && (cl_info.unsafe_anonymous_host() == NULL)) {
  stream = check_class_file_load_hook(stream,
                                      name,
                                      loader_data,
                                      cl_info.protection_domain(),
                                      &cached_class_file,
                                      CHECK_NULL);
}
```

```java
//src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c :
//call java code sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl#transform
transformedBufferObject = (*jnienv)->CallObjectMethod(
   jnienv,
   agent->mInstrumentationImpl, //sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl
   agent->mTransform, //transform
   moduleObject,
   loaderObject,
   classNameStringObject,
   classBeingRedefined,
   protectionDomain,
   classFileBufferObject,
   is_retransformer);
```

**In step 3:**

`VM_RedefineClasses::redefine_single_class(jclass the_jclass, InstanceKlass* scratch_class, TRAPS)` method replaces parts (such as constant pool, methods, etc.) in target class with parts from transformed class.

```java
// src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiRedefineClasses.cpp
for (int i = 0; i < _class_count; i++) {
  redefine_single_class(_class_defs[i].klass, _scratch_classes[i], thread);
}
```

**So how to speed up runtime Java code instrumentation?**

In my project, the `total` time and `max-min` time are almost the same if the app is in a paused state while transforming. can you provide some demo code?

It's impossible to change the way jvm works, so multithreading may not be a bad idea. It got several times faster after using multithreading in my demo project.

Comment: I'd give you more points if I could. This answer really nailed it. Thank you!

Comment: I still have one more question, when does `linking` exactly happen? As far as I can tell you, when I load my agent, all the classes that I wanted to instrument(`classArr`) are instrumented immediately even if no method is called on them(basically my app is in a paused state when the agent is loaded).

Comment: @Nfff3 does it? This answer describes some of the steps that are performed during the transformation process and suggests a change to your agent that doesn’t improve the speed but just changes what you are measuring. How does it solve your problem? I did some experiments and in my setup, 11k classes were transformed within less than one second. So why is it so slow in your case and how did you solve it? If this answer says it, it must be very well hidden somewhere.

Comment: @Holger this answer didn't help in speeding up my agent, but it did help in understanding what the JVM does in the background. I think most of the time is spent in the JVM (I don't know yet why but I am working on my way to finding it).

Comment: I'm working on a native agent, The transform process is a little bit complicated. I can provide a simple POC project to help if you need. and you can refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-5.html to get more info about "Loading, Linking, and Initializing". I will supplement this answer later.

Comment: @RieonKe that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: It's strange that your transformation process is so slow, would you try my jdk fork https://github.com/rieonke/jdk/tree/agent_measure, and it will print some logs while transforming, M_CALL_INSTRU_IMPL means the time spent by sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl#transform, and M_LOAD_NEW_VERSION is the total time spent by step2. you can compare it with your own measurements.

Comment: @Nfff3 I think, it heavily depends on how much the classes were already used, and how. In other words, how much deoptimization is necessary to apply the changes.

Comment: @Holger, I think you are right. When I instrument my 11k classes, they are in a paused state but the app has been already executing for a while so (according to Hotspot code) breakpoints are removed, native code is deoptimized etc. I think this causes the huge slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems like the complete transformation is running in a single thread.

You could create multiple threads, each one is transforming one class at the time. As the transformation of a class should be independent of any other class. This should give you an improvement in the overall transformation time by a factor of the number of used Core available on the executing system.

You can count the cores with:

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Chunk the list of classes to be transformed into the number of cores and create that may threads to process the chunks in parallel.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. See my second update.